# change date format to yyyy-mm-dd from varchar in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
  to_char("date", 'YYYY/MM/DD') 
  "public".teacher_details.teacher_id,
  "public".teacher_details.first_name,
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastCode",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastName",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."DOB",
  "public".teacher_details.dob
FROM
  "public".teacher_details
INNER JOIN "public"."TblFacultyMaster" ON "public"."TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = "public".teacher_details.teacher_id
```

I am trying to convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd and the type is varchar ,  since I have yyyy-mm-dd in format in my TblFacultyMaster table and dd/mm/yyyy in my teachers_deatil table 
I want to match common DOB but the format is different in both table

Help Please

Thanks In advance

Comment: I am matching Few things together and DOB plays an important role for matching the table

Comment: type is varchar and format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Do you mean you store date values in a varchar column? How come?

Comment: Stop storing dates as strings. Use the Date type.

Comment: above query is not working brother
Please Look At the Query , I want to match these things along with DOB column and for that I want to change the date format

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5908629/bunker-boyt in the same query

Comment: the possible way is: first convert to date and then back to char with new format

Comment: I am currently working on this , Our senior had created the database and stored the date as string

Comment: If a "senior" stores dates in varchar columns he is not a "senior"

Comment: to_char(to_date("date", 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: Why are you adding the URL to the user profiles to your comments? If you want to direct a comment to a user prefix the username with a `@`, e.g. `@niyou`

Comment: hi the users dont have the full date, they want to store the data that they have, like year, year and month and rarely full date

Answer (score 1):

`to_char` can not convert string to string, try to typecast with date to the varchar `datecolumn` here i suppose to "date" is your that column, try
 like below :

```
SELECT
  to_char("date"::date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as date, 
  "public".teacher_details.teacher_id,
  "public".teacher_details.first_name,
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastCode",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastName",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."DOB",
  "public".teacher_details.dob
FROM
  "public".teacher_details
INNER JOIN "public"."TblFacultyMaster" ON "public"."TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = "public".teacher_details.teacher_id
```

Comment: Missing a `, `, and should really use `"date"::DATE`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  to_char(to_date(dob, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'YYYY/MM/DD'),  
  "public".teacher_details.teacher_id,
  "public".teacher_details.first_name,
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastCode",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastName",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."DOB",
  "public".teacher_details.dob
FROM
  "public".teacher_details
INNER JOIN "public"."TblFacultyMaster" ON "public"."TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = "public".teacher_details.teacher_id
```

not tested

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_char"
  LINE 2:   to_char(to_date("date", 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'YYYY/MM/DD')  
            ^

Comment: Syntax is correct. What is the fieldname of the date field? And post full Statement and ERROR text

Comment: if your columnname is dob why do you use "date"?

Comment: the field name is dob @niyou

Comment: the type of dob is varchar , I want to match dob of one table to dob of other table , but format is different in both , thats why I am unable to match the dob of both the table @niyou

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL will automatically take it to yyyy-MM-dd when using the to_date() function. See below:

```
select to_date(dob, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as myDate;
```

This will result in the following:

[image]

I hope that helps. Cheers.

EDIT:

Okay I understand what you are trying to do, maybe this will do the trick:

```
SELECT
  to_date("public".teacher_details.dob, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
  "public".teacher_details.teacher_id,
  "public".teacher_details.first_name,
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastCode",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastName",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."DOB",
  "public".teacher_details.dob
FROM
  "public".teacher_details
INNER JOIN "public"."TblFacultyMaster" ON "public"."TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = "public".teacher_details.teacher_id
WHERE to_date("public".teacher_details.dob, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = "public"."TblFacultyMaster".dob
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_date"
  LINE 2:   to_date('16/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as myDate

https://stackoverflow.com/users/8336285/daefect91

Comment: Strange, what version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: version 9.6  @Daefect91

Comment: my column name is dob and I need to  change its format

Comment: Me too, would you mind sending me the full script that you are testing now? Does it work when you use only my line in a separate query?

Comment: I am trying to convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd and the type is varchar , since I have yyyy-mm-dd in format in my TblFacultyMaster table and dd/mm/yyyy in my teachers_deatil table I want to match common DOB but the format is different in both table

so I need to match along with changing the date format of column dob and then I will check if dob of one table matches dob of the other table

@Daefect91

Comment: the type of dob is varchar , I want to match dob of one table to dob of other table , but format is different in both , thats why I am unable to match the dob of both the table @Daefect91