# how do I match these two column field : to_char and dob and the type is varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to match column `dob` to `to_char` but its in different format.

My table field:

```
teacher_id : ANA-2265866    
firstname  : SANJAY KUMAR SHARMA    
mastcode   : 1079655    
mastname   : SANJAY KUMAR SHARMA    
to_char    : 1974-12-11 
dob        : 1974-12-11 00:00:00.000
```

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT
  "public".teacher_details.teacher_id,
  "public".teacher_details.first_name,
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastCode",
  "public"."TblFacultyMaster"."MastName",
  to_char(to_date("public"."TblFacultyMaster"."DOB", 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
  --to_char(to_date((teacher_details.dob), 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
  "public".teacher_details.dob
FROM
  "public".teacher_details
INNER JOIN "public"."TblFacultyMaster"
  ON "public"."TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = "public".teacher_details.teacher_id
--WHERE teacher_details.dob IS NOT NULL OR teacher_details.dob  != ''
```

Comment: Don't do that. What data type is the `dob` column? And what data type is the `to_char` column. Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `teacher_details`

Comment: datatype is varchar in both the field 

https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: To reply to a comment use `@` in front of the username (e.g. `@a_horse_with_no_name`) there is no need to paste the URL to the user's profile. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/q/48276072/330315 seems to be the same question. Are you two co-workers?

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql you can split the date with **date_part()** or **extract()** (see the [guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)).

If the two columns are date, you can use also **date_trunc(text, timestamp)** so you can remove the "time" part of the dob column.

If the to_char column is a string, you must do some conversions with **to_char()** function:

```
to_char = to_char(date_trunc('day', dob),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you want to test some pattern:

```
select to_char(date_trunc('day', current_timestamp),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

More information on [Data Type Formatting Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) page.

In the case of **two varchar** columns, you can simply check

```
dob = substring(to_char from 0 for 11);
```

You can try it with

```
select '1974-12-11' = substring('1974-12-11 00:00:00.000' from 0 for 11), substring('1974-12-11 00:00:00.000' from 0 for 11)
```

Comment: datatype is varchar , but this also doesn't help @Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Never store dates or timestamps in `varchar` columns. Just don't.

To compare the two values you need to convert both strings to proper dates.

The `to_char` column (what a **horrible** name) can be converted like this:

```
to_date("to_char", 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

The dob column stores a timestamp literal and can be converted like this:

```
to_date(dob, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ms')
```

This can be used in a where clause:

```
where to_date("to_char", 'yyyy-mm-dd') = to_date(dob, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ms')
```

---

But you should **really** change those columns to `date` and `timestamp` (and find a better name than `to_char` for the first column)

Comment: I cannot change these column to another data type since its will affect lot of things which is already present

Comment: If I create one more field with dob_date and then copy all data , will it work ?

and how to copy that

@a_horse_with_no_name

https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: @ArchanaGupta: that is a different question. Please do not extend the scope of your initial problem after you have an answer